# Controller for angularjs shell page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I'm developing my first AngularJS app.

master.html is the shell/main page which will load child pages and has it's own logic (i.e. users, search, etc).

The following image shows conceptual structure of my project-

[image]

My app.js -

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/',
    {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/blogslist.html'
        controller: 'BlogListController'
    })
});
```

I want a controller for master.html also. I know I can use `ng-controller` anywhere. But How and where I'll configure the controller for this page?

Thanks.

Comment: _I want a controller for master.html_.....may be a silly question, but why?

Comment: @Jai Surely this could be silly, because i am learning it. Read the question carefully. Anyway, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You can use the `ng-controller` directive on any element on master.html.

Comment: actually my question _why?_ is silly not yours. and agreed with **AnthonyChu**

Comment: @SKPaul As Anthony suggested you can use ng-controller but why do you need this controller? There may be better options based on your needs.

Comment: @skusunam I've updated my question why this controller required. Would you please tell few "better options" you mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this:

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

myApp.controller('masterCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
   // all your logic here
}]);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    .........    
});
```

and you can use `ng-controller` attribute to the wrapper `div` or `body`.

Comment: You are very close to my question. Do I simply need to place the masterCtrl.js file on master.html? or, tell it in myApp.config(...)?  I have ambiguity here.

Comment: for sake of simplicity you can use a separate js file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular UI Router instead of ngRoute. It allows nested views and states - exactly what you need here.